# How to Deal with Inaccurate MSMQ Performance Counters

Tags: msmq

I have a private queue. I am using the following code to efficiently return the number of messages in the queue.

```
    var queuePath = _queue.Path; //_queue is a System.Messaging.MessageQueue object
    if (queuePath.StartsWith("."))
    {
        queuePath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME") + queuePath.Substring(1);
    }
    var queueCounter = new PerformanceCounter("MSMQ Queue","Messages in Queue",queuePath.ToLower(),true);
```

This code *usually* works but it appears to be sometimes wrong (i.e. the value lags the actual length).  How can I force an **MSMQ Queue** counter to be up-to-date?

My test data inserts two items and then checks the length. If I step through it the value is correct but if I run it at full speed, the count comes back as zero.
Is there a better way than a **Performance Counter** for this purpose?

Comment: Found a better way by just enumerating through the queue using `GetMessageEnumerator2()`.  It is reliable but doesn't require all messages be fetched into memory (unlike `GetAllMessages().Length()`).